# kadmind error - krb5_recvauth: start_seq_get is not supported in the HDBGET keytab type

Tags: ubuntu, openldap, kerberos, ubuntu-14.04, heimdal

I'm trying to migrate a heimdal KDC with an OpenLDAP backend from a Debian 5.x server (heimdal 1.2.dfsg.1-2.1) to a Ubuntu 14.04 server (heimdal 1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1), and am running into problems with kadmind on the 14.04 system.

Some kerberos functionality works fine -- I can run kinit, get a ticket and use GSSAPI authentication with sshd successfully. I can even use kadmin with the -l option successfully. However, when I leave out the -l option and try to talk to kadmind, I get errors. For example, if I export the kadmin/admin keytab to the file /tmp/kadmin.keytab and run:

`kadmin -p kadmin/admin -K /tmp/kadmin.keytab get kadmin/admin`

I get the error:

```
kadmind[38823]: krb5_recvauth: start_seq_get is not supported in the HDBGET keytab type
```

This exact same command, with the exact same kadmin.keytab file, works just fine on the debian 5.x system.

The situation in which I get the above error is where I've either copied the /var/lib/heimdal-kdc/heimdal.db file from the Debian 5.x server to the Ubuntu 14.04 server, or the heimdal.db file is nonexistent. If I use the default heimdal.db file that gets created along with the heimdal package installation, I see a different error from kadmind:

```
kadmind[38853]: krb5_recvauth: Decrypt integrity check failed for checksum type hmac-sha1-96-aes256, key type aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
```

I don't understand why the contents of heimdal.db matters, since I'm using an OpenLDAP backend. It seems odd that a static db file is somehow being consulted when the principals are in the LDAP directory. I have verified that I have copied the LDAP directory intact from the Debian 5.x system to the Ubuntu 14.04 system, and there is no master key being used (there is no mkey_file directive, and even if I copy over the default m-key file that was auto-generated originally on the Debian 5.x it doesn't make any difference). Not sure what else I could do to ensure that the configurations are as similar as possible.

I also tried backporting the more recent heimdal 1.6rc2 package to 14.04 but got the same errors. I tried tracing through kadmind's behavior with gdb but nothing jumped out as being an obvious issue.

Does anyone know what might be going on here? Here are /etc/krb5.conf and /etc/heimdal-kdc/kdc.conf files to illustrate the config:

---

```
# /etc/krb5.conf
[libdefaults]
default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
forwardable = true
proxiable = true
renewable = true
scan_interfaces = true

[realms]
EXAMPLE.COM = {
  admin_server = localhost
  kdc = localhost
}

[domain_realm]
example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
.example.com = EXAMPLE.COM

[logging]
default = SYSLOG:INFO
```

---

```
# /etc/heimdal-kdc/kdc.conf
[logging]
kdc = FILE:/var/log/heimdal-kdc.log
kdc = SYSLOG:INFO

[kdc]
database = {
  dbname = ldap:dc=example,dc=com
  hdb-ldap-create-base = ou=Kerberos,dc=example,dc=com
  acl_file = /etc/heimdal-kdc/kadmind.acl
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like various code changes between 1.2 and 1.6 led to the problem that I was seeing. To fix the problem, I did the following:

1. Added the kadmin/admin principal to /etc/krb5.keytab
2. Appended `--keytab=/etc/krb5.keytab` to the kadmind arguments in /etc/inetd.conf

This tells kadmind to explicitly look in /etc/krb5.keytab (instead of "HDBGET:") for the kadmin/admin principal that it uses to authenticate to kdc.

For more information, see https://github.com/heimdal/heimdal/issues/133